# How can I divide a screen in 2 equal parts : one with an image and the other with textviews?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making an Android news app and when I or the user would access a list of news, each news would take the whole screen and would be divided in two parts (50/50) : first part would be the image and the other half would be the textviews (for the title, date and article). A couple of apps are using the same trick.

I've tried many options but I cannot manage to make them fit into my screen and get what I'm looking for.

As you will see I've added the layout_weight parameter but it does not make any difference at all.

Any idea anyone ??

Here's my xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/news_hockey2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="date_of_pub"
        android:id="@+id/date_of_pub"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="link"
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="article"
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If your using an adapter give your main LinearLayout an id like android:id="@+id/mynewslayout". Now lets see your ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the height to 0dp for all the views you want to have resize.  Then you assign all of those views a weight, in the ratio you want them to have.  For example, if you want the top half of the screen to be an image half the screen high, you'd give that image view a weight of 1, and give all the other views a weight that total to 1 and put all of them as 0dp (wrapping all the text views in a 2nd linear layout will make that easier, you can put the weight and 0dp height on the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I was bored so I just wrote it out for you. Basically what you want to do is create two views in a view. Your ImageView is one view and your LinearLayout is the other view. These two views go into the screen view which is a LinearLayout. Each view has a weight of 1 which makes them equal to 50% of the page. All the other views inside the inner LinearLayout can be adjusted.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/news_hockey2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_of_pub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="date_of_pub"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="link"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="article"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The base layout with orientation set to horizontal should contain two child layouts each with layout-weight of 50% then populate these views with whatever you like..

Answer (score 0):

Now, to use @GabeSechan's suggestion **properly**, set the ImageView's weight to **4** and the 4 TextViews weight to **1**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:src="@drawable/news_hockey2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="date_of_pub"
        android:id="@+id/date_of_pub"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="link"
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="article"
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```